# unable to make checkbox checked in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have this code sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/nickbuus/eUufc/15/

where I am trying to make the checkbox have a normal check/uncheck behaviour. It works fine untill I add an onclick event to each checkbox. This onclick event calls this method:

```
 self.saveIsMeasureChecked = function (item)
```

After this method ends the checkbox gets back to its old state before being checked/unchecked - Which makes it appear that you cannot change the state of the checbox at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return `true` from your click event handler in order to trigger the browser default behavior (see also in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html): *Allowing the default click action* section)

```
self.saveIsMeasureChecked = function (item) {
    //Do something
    return true;
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AWpj8/)

However it seems there is something not quite right in Knockout because when you are using the `value` binding and the `click` binding on the checkbox you need to click twice for the first time to make the checkbox change.

But if your are using the `attr` binding to set the value everything seems OK.

```
<input name="cbIsMeasureChecked" type="checkbox" 
       data-bind="attr: {value: foodId}, 
       checked: isMeasureChecked, 
       click: $root.saveIsMeasureChecked" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AWpj8/1/)